# How can I load a file when filename is defined in an external text file?

Tags: java

Given a standard text file that I read in with `Scanner`, where the first line contains the name of an image to read (which is located in the same folder as the text file), how can I use that file name to load the image to display on screen? As it stands right now, I'm getting a `javax.imageio.IIOException` saying "Can't read input file!" and I can't figure out why not.

Here's the text file:

```
MapBig.jpg
2
5
439 203 405 253 431 280 499 257 495 217
5
57 147 164 72 190 127 105 300 70 260
```

Here's my code to read it: `image = ImageIO.read(new File(in.nextLine()));` where `in` is an instance of `Scanner`.

I've also tried using `./MapBig.jpg` in the text file and I get the same problem.

I suppose it should also be noted that I'm reading the text file using `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("map.data");`, as this file is in a source folder in my project... same folder again as the file `MapBig.jpg`

---

Here's a stack trace when the error comes up:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at graphics.MapPanelSettings.<init>(MapPanelSettings.java:32)
    at graphics.GameFrame.initialize(GameFrame.java:71)
    at graphics.GameFrame.<init>(GameFrame.java:49)
    at game.GameLauncher.main(GameLauncher.java:9)
```

Comment: I tried to give a correct answer to your question, but can you post the stack trace error you are getting, so we can easily see what problem is occurring? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the stack trace: It's indeed the wrong input file. You're probably loading the files wrongly, since the input file can't be read. You should also make sure that your `resources` directory is placed correctly. This directory should be **inside** your `src` directory. I explained this more clear in my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed in the proper location.
You can construct proper path by getting location that you want to use with the ClassLoader :

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("map.data");
String fileName = in.nextLine();
String dirPath = new File(url.getPath()).getParent();
File myImage = new File(dirPath, fileName);
```

This should work. Sorry for incomplete original example.

**Edit**
Well, you don't actually need to calculate your path using "map.data" location. You directly use :

```
String fileName = in.nextLine();
URL imageUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName);
File myImage = new File(imageUrl.getPath());
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your image has to be loaded from the file system, not from the .jar file itself. If your image is located elsewhere on your system (other directory than your .jar file is at), you should use a different file name than `MapBig.jpg`. You can change the file name in your `map.data` file, or you add the default directory as prefix to the loaded file name from your `map.data` file.
Whenever the files you want to load are loacated in the Jar file itself, you need to load them as resource. Check the example bellow:

```
URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource(in.nextLine());
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
```

If your image is located in a sub-directory, you need to prepend your file name with the proper directory path, for example:

```
URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource("resources/" + in.nextLine());
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
```

---

You should also debug whether the file name that needs to be loaded is correct. For example, temporarily replace  your `image = ImageIO.read(new File(in.nextLine()));` line with `System.out.println("File to load: " + in.nextLine().toString());` and make sure this name is correct. You can easily use the following script to automatically check whether the file (you're trying to load) exists, and print an error if that's not the case;

```
File f = new File(in.nextLine());
if(f.exists() && f.isFile())
    image = ImageIO.read(f);
else
    System.out.println("Unable to load image, file doesn't exist: " + f.getName());
```

Comment: It's reading the correct filename, but it's not finding that file, as it seems to not be looking in the proper folder.

Comment: You said your files were located in `resources`. Are you sure you are loading the files from this directory? Besides that, are you sure that your resources directory is located inside the `src` directory, and NOT outside this directory? (If not, simply move your resources folder into your `src` directory.
Your directory should be placed like this: http://d.pr/i/as7K

Answer (score 1):

try with this..

```
File file = new File(in.nextLine());
if(file.exists()){
    image = ImageIO.read(file);
} else {
    System.out.println("given file " + file.getName() + " not found.");
}
```

Comment: I'm indeed getting the message printed out to console "given file MapBig.jpg not found."

Comment: are you sure your class also in same folder??

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and this is a fairly large project with various packages and folders. I have a folder called "resources" which holds the image and the data file, while the rest is in the subfolder `/src`. The class files are not in the same folder

Comment: You should prepend your file path with `resources/`. Either you change your file names in your data files, or you prepend your file name strings with this path. For example: `image = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/", in.nextLine()));`

Comment: Also, because you're loading the images from the resources of your Jar file, you need to load the file as resource. I explained this very well in the first part of the answer I gave.

Comment: I think the problem may be stemming from the fact that the folder that my files are in have a space in the path, and the path that gets passed back via URL has a %20 in it.